# Problem when using UI dialog in Jquery UI tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page with 4 tabs which are dynamically loaded. In each of the tab there are links which invoke dialog. The problem is when I refresh one of the tab the UI dialog which was created due to initialization does not get removed and it is recreating again causing the dialog to not function.

Any ideas on how to fix it would be most appreciated. I am kinda stuck and need a solution ASAP.

update: Sorry I forgot to mention that I use ASP .Net MVC 2 and the data for tabs gets refreshed from the controller.

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix the problem was to have a ModalDialogContainer at the parent page and load that dialog with whatever the URL those links had. This way even when the tabs refreshed the outer container (parent) was in tact.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks,
Raja